# Show that the energy levels of a particle in a specific potential are $E_n=(n+\frac{1}{2})h\omega-\frac{1}{2}\frac{F^2}{m\omega^2}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, schroedinger-equation, potential

A particle of mass m moves on the x-axis under the inﬂuence of the potential
$$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2+Fx$$
Can anyone help me, using Schrödinger's equation in one dimension that the energy levels are:
$$E_n=(n+\frac{1}{2})h\omega-\frac{1}{2}\frac{F^2}{m\omega^2}$$
Where n is a non negative integer?

Comment: What have you tried, and what concept exactly is giving you trouble? Remember that this is not a site to get people to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try a change of coordinates $x\rightarrow x-x_0$, where $x_0$ is an appropriate constant.

Answer (score 0):

$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2+Fx=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x^2+\frac{2F}{m\omega^2}x)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2((x+\frac{2F}{m\omega^2})^2-\frac{F^2}{m^2\omega^4})=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x'^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{F^2}{m\omega^2}$ and you have, that it is potential of the oscillator minus constant. So energy levels offset by this constant.